# Error in running the sample database using SQL query in pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to run the SQL query from [the sample database](https://github.com/morenoh149/postgresDBSamples/tree/master/worldDB-1.0) in the pgAdmin 4, but there is an error.

[image: There is a screenshot. Sorry for Russian, it said: "The error of syntax"]

Comment: pgAdmin doesn't support `COPY ... FROM STDIN`, you need to run that with `psql`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, but I don't know how to do that. could you show me, please?

Comment: @kartographinya, all you need is the `psql` command-line program and database connection details like hostname, username and password. See details here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html